# Counting number of members in a disjoint set

Tags: c++, algorithm, disjoint-sets

I am having a little bit of trouble counting the number of elements in each of my disjoint set members. For example, if someone enters in:

Note: first number = source vertex, 2nd number = destination vertex, 3rd number = length

0 2 1

4 8 7

5 8 6

1 2 5

2 3 17

I would have 2 as a count for the set

4 8 7

5 8 6

and 3 as a count for the set as both are connected by 2 and 3 (respective) elements.

0 2 1

1 2 5

2 3 17

I had the idea of storing the count of the number of elements for each disjoint set, into an integer array, so I can access the count for ever disjoint set. Below are my implementations for finding elements and unioning them into the same set. I also have a function for finding the root in every set.

```
int node::findSet(int v, int *parent)
{
  if(parent[v] < 0)
    return v;
  else
  {
    return parent[v] = findSet(parent[v], parent);
  }
}

void node::joinSets(int c, int p1, int p2, int *parents)
{
  join(findSet(p1,parents),findSet(p2,parents),parents);
}

void node::join(int p1, int p2, int *parents)
{
  if(parents[p2] < parents[p1])
    parents[p1] = p2;
  else
  {
    if(parents[p1] == parents[p2])
      parents[p1]--;
    parents[p2] = p1;
  }
}
```

I'm just not sure where/when to increment and maintain my counter. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you have 2 and 3 as disjoint sets' sizes. Do you count edges instead of vertices? To me the sizes are 3 and 4...

Comment: BTW I like your implementation of find-union with parents and ranks in a single array. Very memory-efficient, I haven't seen something like this yet;)

Comment: Yes, sorry I am counting edges instead of vertices in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to count the number of edges connecting each disjoint set, store the current size of every root in an array similar to `parents`.

When an edge comes, find roots of both nodes. If they're equal, increment the counter for the root (I'm assuming there are no repeating edges). If they're not, union the roots, and for the resultant root's counter value put the sum of the roots' counter values plus one.

Comment: Okay. Just one question then--how would you find the current size of every root?

Comment: At the beginning each size is obviously 0. Then you modify them as you add edges...

Comment: Okay. Now I have figured out how to get my size of each edge. Now I have one question then--how would I print out each set of disjoint sets based on their size? Thank you for the help by the way!

Comment: I believe the most optimal you can do is n log n. Sort your nodes by their root numbers (by output of `findSet`) and then print nodes until the root number changes. That's the first set. Then print the second set until the root number changes again and so on.

Comment: yes, I definitely thought of that. I have that implemented. However, I want to print each set by the number of edges they have. For example, if set 1 has 2 cities in it, i want to print that one first over one that would have 3 cities in it. My issue is this: if a user enters in 0 1 1 then 4 5 6 then 4 6 8 then 0 2 2, it'll print 0 1 1 as one set, then 4 5 6 and 4 6 8 as another region, then 0 2 2. But 0 2 2 are connected, so I want to print them together as one set. Might you have any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Then you should sort the nodes by the number of edges in a node's set, and by root number in the second order. That is, if two nodes are in sets of different size, the one in smaller set comes first, but if the sizes are the same, then the one whose root's number is lower comes first. Later divide the list on root number changes, as previously.

Comment: Yeah, just having trouble sorting the node by the number of edges in a node's set efficiently. The way I came up with was an array very similar to parent. However, I'm not able to compare the sizes with other root sizes and print out those with the same roots either...

Comment: Is there any linear time algorithm to print the elements of a set in any order?Like Print-Set(x) should print all the member's of x's set.Could this be done in linear time.